# Stop input field code from being escaped in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a text field that needs to have code posted in it. Unfortunately in SilverStripe the code is automatically escaped, which just shows that code itself in the front end.

Is there a way to make it execute the code instead?

I have tried the following:

```php
public static $db = array(
    'Code' => 'Text'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay found a way to do this you need to append a RAW method to his in the template, like so : `$Code.RAW`

Comment: you might accept your own answer, cause it's correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think an alternative solution to this would be to make the type of your field HTMLText instead of Text. In that case you wouldn't have to use RAW.

Comment: No that will not work since the everything is escaped there and the edior only lets certain tag trough :)

Comment: What Mark Guinn is suggesting is define the `$db` variable as `'Code' => 'HTMLText'`. Then still use a `TextareaField` for your field, not a `HTMLEditorField`. This will work with any html tag.